# Passt hier "geltend machen"?

Tags: verb

> Der Auftragnehmer hat keinen Anspruch, Verluste, Schäden oder
>   entgangenen Gewinn geltend zu machen.

Ich habe mich [daran](http://www.infomedia.co.at/inframing/moore/artikel_493.php?UID=493&TID=33299&newPage=) orientiert, aber ich habe noch Zweifel.

Comment: Ja, passt. *Geltend machen* im Sinne von *auf vertragsgültige Weise einfordern*.

Comment: Vielleicht magst Du noch dazu schreiben, was genau Dich zweifeln lässt? Unter Umständen bekommst Du dadurch eine passgenaue Antwort. :)

Comment: Danke für Eure Hilfe.

Answer (score 4):

*Anspruch* und *geltend machen* empfinde ich als doppelte Wendung, da "geltend machen" bereits einen Anspruch impliziert.
Meinem Gefühl nach wären "Der Auftragnehmer hat keinen Anspruch auf Erstattung von Verlusten, Schäden oder entgangenem Gewinn." oder aber "Der Auftragnehmer kann Verluste, Schäden oder entgangenen Gewinn nicht geltend machen." bessere Formulierungen.

Comment: Danke für Deine Vorschläge.